# Dynamically adjust window height to match the content when iframe preload is false?

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using Fancybox2 for my web application and load conent into an iframe. I would like to load iframe faster. I have read the following two SO posts:

[fancybox 2 iframe loading issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840336/fancybox-2-iframe-loading-issue)

[Fancybox stuck loading iframe in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819642/fancybox-stuck-loading-iframe-in-ie)

Here is what I have:

```
type: 'iframe',
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
            modal: true,  
            width: 900, //I need to set the width of the iframe
            iframe: {
                preload: false 
            } 
});
```

The load seems faster by using `preload: false`. However, when the fancybox is shown, its height is always 600 (the default value in Fancybox2). I also tried

```
height: 'auto'
```

and

```
height: '100%'
```

The auto option actually generates a window of about 100 pixels tall (which is too short), and the 100% option makes the window use all the available height, (which is too much).

Is Fancybox able to dynamically adjust its height when being configured with the following settings? Through configuration? Or programming?

```
iframe: {
    preload: false 
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/mddc/6e26Lgps/7/

Comment: You want iframe to match content height before content is loaded? I wonder if this is possible.

Comment: If preload is set to false (which is the defualt), Fancybox is able to dynamically math the cotent height or show a scroll bar is the content is too much.