# fancybox iframe doesn't work in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox in a bought multipurpose template called YALU.
However Fancybox iframes doesn't work in IE 8. The overlay opens, but no content is loaded (white content). I also tried to disable the preload function in fancybox with no effect.

All other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, even IE 9) are working good. 
You can have a [look here](http://yalu.melcher.de/gallery.html)(click the first sample image).

I've been looking for a solution for days now, but haven't found any yet.

Here is some source code from the Template:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
[...]
```

This is part of the jquery script:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
if(jQuery().fancybox) {
    jQuery('.openfancybox').fancybox();
} 
[...]
```

This is my a-Tag:

```
<a data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="404.html" class="openfancybox fancybox.iframe">...</a>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance
Jan

Answer (score 2):

**I solved this problem**

This has been caused by a wrong css declaration for the html-tag which has been set to *position:relative*

Changing into *absolute* solved it for IE8. In fact I don'r really understand this, but it works and thats all I wanted.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Personally, I never like setting position or dimensions (`width` and `height`) to neither the `html` or `body` tags but using wrapper containers instead, otherwise potentially creates lots of conflicts with many plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling `iframe` `preload` in your your [code](http://yalu.melcher.de/files/js/script.js) like :

```
if (jQuery().fancybox) {
    jQuery('.openfancybox').fancybox({
        iframe: {
            preload: false // fixes possible issues with iframes and IE
        }
    });
}
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14828632/1055987) for further reference.

**EDIT #1** :

I don't think is a fancybox releated issue. There is something in your page (a script perhaps) that prevents it from being displayed inside an iframe using IE.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/mgENw/show/ in IE.

Also, your main page trows this error (IE) on page load :
[image]

Comment: Hi JFK, thanks for your answer.
I already tried setting preload to false - with no effect.
In fact your jsfiddle-link doesn't open my 404.html page in IE8

I think it really maybe any other jSqript from the YALU Template which knocks out the fancybox.iframe functionallity.

Jan