# fancybox-1.3.4 doesn't work in iE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, fancybox

I have following sample of code i want to open video in a fancybox it works fine almost across all browsers except when i try to test it in IE 8 standard mode.

It works fine in IE 9 and above.

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819642/fancybox-stuck-loading-iframe-in-ie) i added following line of code but this doesn't make it work either `iframe: { preload: false   }`

HTML Deceleration code is as

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
    <html lang="en">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    .........
```

**Sample Code**

```
<div class="video-icon">
  <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CR0AXNtwqZE?autoplay=1" class="fancybox-video"><img src="coorporate-video-icon.jpg"/></a>
</div>


             $("a.fancybox-video").fancybox({
                width: 600,
                height: 440,
                closeClick: true,
                hideOnOverlayClick: true,
                type: 'iframe',
                iframe: { preload: false // fixes issue with iframe and IE
                }
            });
```

I am not sure what breaks it i cant create a fiddle example as fiddle doesn't work in IE 8 any help in this regard is appreciated.

**UPDATE**: i tried it with fancybox Version 2.1.3 but i still face the same problem..

Comment: Why don't you use Fancybox 2 ? Fancybox 1 is discontinued for some days.

Comment: The solution in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819642/fancybox-stuck-loading-iframe-in-ie) is for fancybox v2.x. Fancybox 2.x options are incompatible with v1.x

Comment: @ShivanRaptor : the reason people may not want to use v2.x is because its license limitations so they prefer to stick to v1.3.4 (which it's not discontinued)

Comment: Guys I want to use the free version without any license issues. for this reason i am using fb-1.x.x

Comment: @JFK, is their any fix for this in if one is using version 1.3.4 or only option is v2. I would appreciate your reply on this

Comment: Are you using a doctype?

Comment: Yes i am using it as `<!DOCTYPE html >` as i want to make it as HTML 5

Answer (score 1):

`it doesn't work` doesn't really tell what the problem is.

If it didn't even work with v2.1.3, then you may have other issues. This is your check list for troubleshooting IE:

- Make sure you have a proper `DOCTYPE`, and the `DOCTYPE` is the first line of your html document so IE won't switch to quirks mode.
- Make sure you are wrapping your custom script inside the `.ready()` method.
- Make sure you are using the right fancybox options
- Make sure you don't have any extra trialing comma after the last option
- Check for other script conflicts (syntax errors of other scripts may stop fancybox from working)
- Make sure you don't have any other js error. Check IE isn't showing this icon (bottom-left corner of the browser) :

  [image]

Otherwise, this html

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CR0AXNtwqZE?autoplay=1" class="fancybox-video"><img src="coorporate-video-icon.jpg"/></a>
```

and this jQuery code,  both work fine in IE[7-9] using fancybox v1.3.4 :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("a.fancybox-video").fancybox({
        width: 600,
        height: 440,
        hideOnContentClick: true, // closeClick: true, // this for v2.x
        hideOnOverlayClick: true,
        type: 'iframe'
    });
}); // ready
```

See DEMO at http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/youtubeEmbedIframe_07jan14.html

Comment: I solved issue by using Jquery 1.9.x along with Fancybox V2 as it come with the theme which i had purchased.  I tried to fix issue with fancyboxv1.8.3 but it kept on generating issue due one or other reason. Error was also due to use of `browser.msie` in FB detection which generated following error 'jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2 character 59313` .. So lesson learn use the correct js file when using plugin... also other error `TypeError: $.browser is undefined` ...

Comment: I finally changed to fancybox v2 after few changes i managed to make it work. in IE 8 i have not tried it with IE 7 as i am not planning to support IE 7 otherwise i might have to drop of useful features which might not work well in IE 7. so far support for IF 8 is more than enough and we still have small number of user for IE 8. Regarding using fancybox v1 i noticed that fancybox.js had some support problem with jquery 1.8.3 regarding use of nth element may be that was creating some sort of conflict so i am now using jquery 1.9.x and fancyboxV2 as it comes part of theme purchase..

Comment: For the record, my demo uses jQuery 1.8.3 + fancybox v1.3.4 and works just fine in IE. You may know that fancybox v1.3.4 doesn't work with jQuery v1.9+, you can see a work around here http://stackoverflow.com/q/14344289/1055987 though