# Increase fancy box loading speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I am using [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/home) popup for load external url on my site but it take a lot of time to load how can I reduce loading time.

```
 jq = jQuery.noConflict( true );
     jq('.fancybox').fancybox({
         'width'  : 566,// set the width
         'speedIn : 1000,   
     });

});


<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.xyz.com/smin/index.php/Reg/site">
```

Comment: if you open the same page in a new window/tab, does it take as long as inside fancybox?

Comment: also, try setting iframe `preload` to `false` Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14828632/1055987